# How can I retrieve the information of a Sim card if it is changed in one of the dual Sim slots?

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

I know we can retrieve the information of a single Sim card using TelephonyManager Class. But how can I retrieve the information about multiple sim cards? Say, my phone is lost and someone changes the sim card in one of the slots. How do I receive the information including IMEI number, phone number etc? I want these information only when Sim card  is changed.

In TelephonyManager class there are direct methods to retrieve those information's(like IMEI number, phone mumber,Phone network type etc)but the information is available only about one Sim card. How do I receive all information about multiple sim cards. 
P.S-The SubscriptionManager class does not have direct methods like TelephonyManager class.

```
    import android.content.Context;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.telephony.SubscriptionInfo;
import android.telephony.SubscriptionManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import static android.R.id.content;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int subID,simposition,content;
        String carrier,number;
        TextView textView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        SubscriptionManager subManager=(SubscriptionManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

        List<SubscriptionInfo> subInfoList=subManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

        for(int i=0;i<subInfoList.size();i++)
        {
           subID = subInfoList.get(i).getSubscriptionId();
            simposition = subInfoList.get(i).getSimSlotIndex();
             content=subInfoList.get(i).describeContents();
          carrier= (String) subInfoList.get(i).getCarrierName();
            number= subInfoList.get(i).getNumber();
        }

       /* String info2="Sim Details:\n";
        info2+="\n SubId:"+subID;
        info2+="\n Sim position:"+simposition;
        info2+="\n contents:"+content;
        info2+="\n carrier:"+carrier;
        info2+="\n number:"+number;
        textView2.setText(info2);*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some sample code that you have written for accessing dual sim cards information, Thanks.

Comment: Done. Please check. I'm a novice in Android. So please forgive the obvious mistakes.

Comment: That's ok, we all started somewhere :) And now with the code we can solve the problem more specifically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this working sample code for solving your problem.

Reference link: https://github.com/ITger/DualSIMCard

Example code from class:
https://github.com/ITger/DualSIMCard/blob/master/dualSIMcardReader/src/main/java/pl/itger/dualsimcard/TelInfo.java

```
    /**
     * Created by piotrz on 7/23/15.
     * Copyright 2015 Piotr Zerynger ITger
     */

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.telephony.CellInfo;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation;

    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import static pl.itger.dualsimcard.MainActivity.getMActContext;

    public final class TelInfo {

        private static TelInfo telInf;
        protected Sci[] scitems;
        ArrayList<Sci> scitemsArr;
        //private String imsiSIM1;
        private String imsiSIM2;
        private boolean isSIM1Ready;
        private boolean isSIM2Ready;
        private String sim1_STATE;
        private String sim2_STATE;
        // Integrated circuit card identifier (ICCID)
        private String sim1_ICCID;
        private String sim2_ICCID;
        // International mobile subscriber identity (IMSI)
        private String sim1_IMSI;
        private String sim2_IMSI;
        // Service provider name (SPN)
        private String sim1_SPN;
        private String sim2_SPN;
        // Mobile country code (MCC)
        private String sim1_MCC;
        private String sim2_MCC;
        // Mobile network code (MNC)
        private String sim1_MNC;
        private String sim2_MNC;

        //private NeighboringCellInfo nci;

        //private  List<NeighboringCellInfo> sim1_NC;
        //private  List<NeighboringCellInfo> sim2_NC;
        private String sim1_MCC_MNC;
        private String sim2_MCC_MNC;
        // Mobile subscriber identification number (MSIN)
        // Mobile station international subscriber directory number (MSISDN)
        private String sim1_MSISDN;
        private String sim2_MSISDN;


        // Abbreviated dialing numbers (ADN)
        // Last dialed numbers (LDN)
        // Short message service (SMS)
        // Language preference (LP)
        // Card holder verification (CHV1 and CHV2)
        // Ciphering key (Kc)
        // Ciphering key sequence number
        // Emergency call code
        // Fixed dialing numbers (FDN)
        //getDeviceId() Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones.
        private String sim1_IMEI;
        private String sim2_IMEI;
        // Local area identity (LAI)
        private String sim1_LAI;
        private String sim2_LAI;
        // Location Area Code (LAC).
        private String sim1_LAC;
        private String sim2_LAC;


        // Own dialing number
        // Temporary mobile subscriber identity (TMSI)
        // Routing area identifier (RIA) network code
        // Service dialing numbers (SDNs)
        // CellID
        private String sim1_CellID;
        private String sim2_CellID;
        private List<CellInfo> all;


        private TelInfo() {
        }

        /*@
       @requires context != null;
       @ensures TelInfo != null;
          @*/
        public static TelInfo getInstance() {//Context context) {
            //if (TelInfo.telInf != null) {
            TelInfo.telInf = null;
            TelInfo.telInf = new TelInfo();
            //}
            Context context = getMActContext();
            //printTelephonyManagerMethodNamesForThisDevice(context);
            //System.out.println("1 " + context);

            TelephonyManager telMngr = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
            //System.out.println("2 " + telMngr);

            //telInf.nci = new NeighboringCellInfo(NeighboringCellInfo.UNKNOWN_RSSI, new GsmCellLocation().toString(), TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA);
            //System.out.println(telInf.nci.toString());


            telInf.sim1_ICCID = telMngr.getSimSerialNumber();
            telInf.sim1_IMSI = telMngr.getSubscriberId();
            telInf.sim1_SPN = telMngr.getSimOperatorName();
            telInf.sim1_MCC = telMngr.getNetworkCountryIso();
            telInf.sim1_MNC = telMngr.getNetworkOperatorName();
            telInf.sim1_MCC_MNC = telMngr.getSimOperator();
            telInf.sim1_MSISDN = telMngr.getLine1Number();
            telInf.sim1_IMEI = telMngr.getDeviceId();
            //telInf.sim1_NC = telMngr.getNeighboringCellInfo();

            if (telMngr.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
                final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telMngr.getCellLocation();
                if (location != null) {
                    telInf.sim1_LAC = Integer.toString(location.getLac());
                    telInf.sim1_CellID = Integer.toString(location.getCid());
                }
            }

            telInf.imsiSIM2 = null;

            telInf.isSIM1Ready = telMngr.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
            telInf.isSIM2Ready = false;

            telInf.sim1_STATE = simState(telMngr.getSimState());
            try {
                //telInf.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                telInf.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
                //System.out.println("!!");
            } catch (ITgerMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (telInf.isSIM2Ready) {
                try {
                    // telInf.sim1_IMSI = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                    telInf.imsiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_ICCID = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getSimSerialNumber", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_IMSI = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getSubscriberId", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_SPN = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getSimOperatorName", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_MCC = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getNetworkCountryIso", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_MNC = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getNetworkOperatorName", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_MCC_MNC = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getSimOperator", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_MSISDN = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getLine1Number", 1);
                    telInf.sim2_IMEI = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);

                    if (telMngr.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
                        final GsmCellLocation location = getCellLocBySlot(context, "getCellLocation", 1);// telMngr.getCellLocation();
                        if (location != null) {
                            telInf.sim2_LAC = Integer.toString(location.getLac());
                            telInf.sim2_CellID = Integer.toString(location.getCid());
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println("!");
                } catch (ITgerMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                    //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            telInf.scitemsArr = new ArrayList<Sci>();

            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("SIM 1 state", telInf.sim1_STATE));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Integrated circuit card identifier (ICCID)", telInf.sim1_ICCID));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Unique device ID (IMEI or MEID/ESN for CDMA)", telInf.sim1_IMEI));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("International mobile subscriber identity (IMSI)", telInf.sim1_IMSI));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Service provider name (SPN)", telInf.sim1_SPN));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile country code (MCC)", telInf.sim1_MCC));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile operator name", telInf.sim1_MNC));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile country code + mobile network code (MCC+MNC)", telInf.sim1_MCC_MNC));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile station international subscriber directory number (MSISDN)", telInf.sim1_MSISDN));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Location Area Code (LAC)", telInf.sim1_LAC));
            telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Cell Tower ID (CID)", telInf.sim1_CellID));

            if (telInf.isSIM2Ready) {
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci(" ", " "));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("SIM 2 state", telInf.sim2_STATE));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Integrated circuit card identifier (ICCID)", telInf.sim2_ICCID));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Unique device ID (IMEI or MEID/ESN for CDMA)", telInf.sim2_IMEI));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("International mobile subscriber identity (IMSI)", telInf.sim2_IMSI));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Service provider name (SPN)", telInf.sim2_SPN));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile country code (MCC)", telInf.sim2_MCC));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile operator name", telInf.sim2_MNC));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile country code + mobile network code (MCC+MNC)", telInf.sim2_MCC_MNC));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Mobile station international subscriber directory number (MSISDN)", telInf.sim2_MSISDN));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Location Area Code (LAC)", telInf.sim2_LAC));
                telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("Cell Tower ID (CID)", telInf.sim2_CellID));


                //telInf.scitemsArr.add(new Sci("NC (Neighboring Cell ", telInf.sim1_NC.toString() ));

            }

            return telInf;
        }

        private static String simState(int simState) {
            switch (simState) {
                case 0:
                    return "UNKNOWN";
                case 1:
                    return "ABSENT";
                case 2:
                    return "REQUIRED";
                case 3:
                    return "PUK_REQUIRED";
                case 4:
                    return "NETWORK_LOCKED";
                case 5:
                    return "READY";
                case 6:
                    return "NOT_READY";
                case 7:
                    return "PERM_DISABLED";
                case 8:
                    return "CARD_IO_ERROR";
            }
            return "??? " + simState;
        }

        private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws ITgerMethodNotFoundException {

            String imsi = null;
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
                parameter[0] = int.class;
                Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

                Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
                obParameter[0] = slotID;
                Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

                if (ob_phone != null) {
                    imsi = ob_phone.toString();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ITgerMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
            }

            return imsi;
        }

        private static GsmCellLocation getCellLocBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws ITgerMethodNotFoundException {

            GsmCellLocation cloc = null;
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
                parameter[0] = int.class;
                Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

                Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
                obParameter[0] = slotID;
                Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

                if (ob_phone != null) {
                    cloc = (GsmCellLocation) ob_phone;

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ITgerMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
            }

            return cloc;
        }

        private static boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws ITgerMethodNotFoundException {
            boolean isReady = false;
            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            try {
                Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
                parameter[0] = int.class;
                Method getSimState = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);
                Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
                obParameter[0] = slotID;
                Object ob_phone = getSimState.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

                if (ob_phone != null) {
                    int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
                    telInf.sim2_STATE = simState(simState);
                    if ((simState != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) && (simState != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN)) {
                        isReady = true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new ITgerMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
            }

            return isReady;
        }

        public static void printTelephonyManagerMethodNamesForThisDevice(Context context) {

            TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class<?> telephonyClass;
            try {
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
                telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
                Method[] methods = telephonyClass.getMethods();

                for (Method method : methods) {
                    // if (methods[idx].getName().startsWith("get")) {
                    System.out.println("\n" + method.getName() + " declared by " + method.getDeclaringClass());//+ "  superclass " + methods[idx].getDeclaringClass().getSuperclass().getName());
                    //}
                }
                System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
            return isSIM1Ready;
        }

        public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
            return isSIM2Ready;
        }

        private boolean isDualSIM() {
            return imsiSIM2 != null;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX TelInfo{" +
                    "imsiSIM1='" + sim1_IMSI + '\'' +
                    ", imsiSIM2='" + imsiSIM2 + '\'' +
                    ", isSIM1Ready=" + isSIM1Ready +
                    ", isSIM2Ready=" + isSIM2Ready +
                    '}';
        }

        private static class ITgerMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

            public ITgerMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
                super(info);
            }

        }
    }
```

I hope this helps.